# How to Call Default.aspx.cs page method from Jquery Ajax?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, c#-3.0

I have a registration form(Default.aspx) which initially show's only 2 field's and a button (Name, email) when user click's on button Jquery makes an Ajax call to Default.aspx.cs function which query db to check for the user, and if it return no then the form expands itself adding registration fields.

I am not able to make a call to Defualt.aspx.cs
my Default.aspx code is :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnDownload').click(function() {
                //$('#secondary').toggle(1000)
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/PassData",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: AjaxSucceeded,
                    error: AjaxFailed
                });
            });
            function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
                alert(result.d);
            }
            function AjaxFailed(result) {
                alert('Failed');
            } 
        });

    </script>
```

And Default.aspx.cs is (for test purpose) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private static string PassData(string id)
    {
        return "Pass";
    }
}
```

But every-time I run the code JS returns error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: com is not defined
POST http://localhost:2305/temp/Default.aspx/PassData 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

I check few posts but non of them had been answered/resolved.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error on the server?  If it's returning a `500` then there's likely more information about the error somewhere.  Application logs, event viewer, body of the response, etc.

Comment: Hi @David: the detail is :

POST http://localhost:2305/temp/Default.aspx/PassData 500 (Internal Server Error)
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
f.extend.ajaxjquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
(anonymous function)Default.aspx:14
f.event.dispatchjquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
f.event.add.h.handle.ijquery-1.7.1.min.js:3

Comment: That's the client-side error.  A `500` response means the server encountered an error.  That error probably contains useful information (as errors are wont to do).

Comment: @David : Where can I find that error ??

Comment: Any number of places.  If your application writes errors to a log (which is usually a good idea), check that log.  If the error was unhandled by the application, there might be something in the event viewer.  There might even be something in the body of the `500` response.

Comment: Thats really helpfull @David, the error log says : Exception information: Exception type: ArgumentException Exception message: Unknown web method PassData. Parameter name: methodName

Answer (score 3):

You need to decorate the method with [WebMethod] attribute.

**EDIT**

You'll need to add a ScriptManager and use some ASP.NET ajax framework methods. I think what you want to do is impossible with the out-of-the-box functionality.

One option will be to create a HttpHandler that will handle those methods. If the request is a POST, you can find the page type from the url (there's a method in the framework but I can't remember which one, you'll need to investigate), create a new instance and check if the method has the WebMethod (or another attribute you like). If it does, you can call it using reflection and render the result.

**EDIT**

As @Antony Highsky pointed out, it's possible. I think the solution is to add the [WebMethod] attribute and make de method public (it's private in the example).

Comment: In addition, there is an EnableSession parameter you may or may not want to set to true.

Comment: I tried putting it     [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] , but no luck, still responds the same error.

Comment: You can find a small tutorial here http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/03/13/asp.net-ajax-callbacks-to-web-methods-in-aspx-pages.aspx

Comment: http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Call-WebMethod-from-Javascript-in-ASPNET.aspx this is another useful one

Comment: It's possible. See http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Use **[WebMethod]

```
[WebMethod]
private static string PassData(string id)
{
    return "Pass";
}
```